# Почему div с классом head не прикрепляется к правой стороне? как заставить при прокрутке контейнера оставаться прикрепленным справа?

Tags: html, css

Почему div с классом head не прикрепляется к правой стороне? как заставить при прокрутке контейнера оставаться прикрепленным справа?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background: green;
            position: sticky;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        .head {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #000;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        .content {
            width: 1000px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему div с классом head не прикрепляется к правой стороне?

У тебя не соответствие ширины контейнера и правого здвига

> как заставить при прокрутке контейнера оставаться прикрепленным справа?

Заменить на `left: calc(100% - 100px);`

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  position: sticky;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.head {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
}

.content {
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: он все равно слева расположен у вас

Comment: @uitsuuiuitsu, это я сначала не правильно понял твой вопрос. :( Поправил свой ответ.

Comment: ещё вопросик есть

Comment: @uitsuuiuitsu, не нашел вопроса... :(

Comment: как сделать чтобы это работало при абсолютном позиционировании .head?

Comment: @uitsuuiuitsu, нашел - смотрю...